# ::before element aligned to the right

Tags: html, css

I have a button which already uses an ::after element (underneath) , but I want to add a shape/element to the right side of the div.

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #d11e5d;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

a.btn-contact::before {
  background: #0c0;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="btn-contact">button</a>
```

I got it to the right of the link, but I want it to vertically align on the right

EDIT: full css/html provided. Wordpress site with .btn-contact class applied to just one button (the one I want the shape beside)

Comment: can you post the rest of you html/css so we can see what you're working with currently?

Comment: To answer rightly your question, we need the HTML composition of both elements, and also it CSS.

Comment: I apologize, I updated my question with full content

Comment: where's the html for `.screen-nav li.btn-contact a` and `.screen-nav li a` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i changed a bit the html you provided ( guessing that it's what you want )

do not use `float` to `absolute` elements. it doesn't have any effect.

use `top:50%` which means half of `li a` height ( the item with position relative ) and also `transform:translateY(-50%)` which moves up `:before` width half of it's height.

these 2 styles together vertical-align in the middle the `before` pseudo-element

check snippet below and let me know if this is what you were looking for

```css
 li a {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 15px 10px;
   margin: 0 5px;
   color: #222;
   font-size: 0.9em;
   font-weight: 700;
 }
 
 li a:after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #d11e5d;
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: 3px;
   width: 0;
   bottom: 6px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
 }
 
 li.btn-contact a::before {
   background: #0c0;
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 50%;
transform:translateY(-50%)
 }
```

```html
<li class="btn-contact"><a href="">button</a></li>
```

Comment: That's exactly it, Thank you